# Why I'm getting unnecessary line break while writing to a file?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlrd

I have a excel file from where I read some data and based on some logic I write the excel file contents to a separate file in addition to some additional data.
I'm done with everything except for this unnecessary line break which I'm getting.

**My Program:**

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

def create_script():
    exl_file = open_workbook('DATA_SHEET.xls')
    data_sheet = exl_file.sheet_by_index(0)

    script_file.write("#Setting Inputs to FALSE values" + '\n\n')

    for row_idx in range(1, data_sheet.nrows):
        for col_idx in range(1):
            data_type = data_sheet.cell(row_idx,col_idx).value
            cell_text = data_sheet.cell(row_idx,col_idx+2).value
            if (data_type == 'Boolean'):
                if ('TRUE' not in cell_text) and (',' not in cell_text):
                    book.seek(0)
                    for line in book:
                        if('%' in line):
                            page_name = line
                        if(cell_text in line):
                            for src, target in replacement.iteritems():
                                page_name = page_name.replace(src, target)
                            cmd = "SET 'ABC." + page_name + ".IO_" + cell_text + "' [ FALSE ]" + "\n"
                            script_file.write(cmd)
                            break;  

replacement = {'%':'', ':modifiable':''}
script_file = open('script.txt', 'w')
book = open('lookupfile.txt', 'r')
create_script()
script_file.close()
book.close()
```

**Actual Output which I'm getting:**

```
#Setting Inputs to FALSE values

SET 'ABC.Page_1
.IO_Variable_1' [ FALSE ]
SET 'ABC.Page_2
.IO_Variable_2' [ FALSE ]
SET 'ABC.Page_3
.IO_Variable_3' [ FALSE ]
SET 'ABC.Page_4
.IO_Variable_4' [ FALSE ]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
#Setting Inputs to FALSE values

SET 'ABC.Page_1.IO_Variable_1' [ FALSE ]
SET 'ABC.Page_2.IO_Variable_2' [ FALSE ]
SET 'ABC.Page_3.IO_Variable_3' [ FALSE ]
SET 'ABC.Page_4.IO_Variable_4' [ FALSE ]
```

As you can see, I'm getting the line breaks after Page_1, Page_2 and so on.
I believe there is some issue in this line, but not able to find out exact cause.

```
cmd = "SET 'ABC." + page_name + ".IO_" + cell_text + "' [ FALSE ]" + "\n"
```

What might be the issue here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a trailing newline:

```
page_name.rstrip()
```

So cmd should look like:

```
 cmd = "SET 'ABC.{}.IO_{}' [ FALSE ]\n".format(page_name.rstrip(),cell_text)
```